# Xcode 4.3.2 organizer freezes

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4.3, xcode-organizer

I have a problem with Xcode's organizer. Whenever I click on it to launch it everything freezes. I have to force quit Xcode and expensive bash process.

I tried to:

1. Restart MAC
2. Reinstall Xcode
3. Kill bash process many times while "loading" Organizer
4. Followed [How to Empty Caches and Clean All Targets Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4/6247073#6247073)

I tried practically everything I found about it here, but nothing worked.
I've seen similar questions here, but people usually had problem with already working Organizer and the things from list above helped them.

Any ideas what I could do about it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for kicks:

Try creating a ***new user*** account on your Macintosh and see if Xcode organizer works better for you on that other account. I've heard anecdotally that there are some cached files that don't get deleted or wiped when you delete or reinstall Xcode and you might be running into an issue related to that.

And if that does turn out to be a solution, file a bug with Apple (at bugreporter.apple.com). The Xcode team needs to be made aware of problems like this.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, on the new account there is no problem with organizer. I'm going to file a bug and in the meantime I'll try to hard-reset Xcode.

Comment: Ok, hard restart did the work. Everything is ok now, thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same set of problems on Xcode 4.5.2. Trying a hard reset as mentioned by Gricha, with the commands below, while required, still didn't solve it.

```
defaults delete com.apple.Xcode

defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode

rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Xcode
```

Finally, I hit Shift-Command-2 to bring the organiser up - and noticed that there is a "null" project in there. Deleting the null project finally got the organizer to work.